# Pass parameter from gui to function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to pass values from the interface to a function.

My run button in `mygui.m`:

```
function btnRun_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    handles.k.train = get(handles.txtTrain,'String');
    handles.k.test = get(handles.txtTest,'String');
    guidata( hObject, handles );

    test = process( handles.k);
```

My function (`process.m`):

```
function [ output_args ] = process( k)
     sprintf('tain=%s', k.train);
     sprintf('test=%s', k.test);
     output_args = 0;
end
```

Nothing is getting printed on the screen. I want the values from my two textboxes to be usable in the function.

Comment: Try `fprintf` instead. Or use the debugger

Comment: Thanks a lot, `fprintf` worked. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When printing formatted strings to the screen, one can use [fprintf](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) in Matlab. Using `fprintf` without any `fileID` will print to standard output (i.e. the screen), where `fileID=1`.

```
>> fprintf('Hello World\n')
Hello World
>>
```

Setting `fileID=2` means standard error, which will print the string in red.

Comment: Also if you use `fprintf ( 2, 'Hello red world\n' )` it displays the text in `red` which can be useful! :)

Comment: @matlabgui You are quite right, I updated the answer.